# Devise user with Polymorphic association for different user profiles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, polymorphism, polymorphic-associations

I have a Rails app. I installed Devise. I want to have a polymorphic association between the User model and the different profiles, for example: Student and Mentor.

This is what I'm trying to do: have a student registration page with the regular devise fields such as: `email`, `password`, `password_confirmation`. But I also want to have fields specific to the Student Profile, such as `residency_type` and `graduation_year`

```
user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :profile, polymorphic: true

student_profile.rb
class StudentProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user, as: :profile, dependent: :destroy

registrations_controller.rb
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def new_student_registration
    resource = build_resource({})
    respond_with resource
  end
...
```

I can create a User with a student profile on the console, like this...

```
u = User.new
u.email = "something@whatever"
... (password and password confirmation)
u.profile = StudentProfile.new
u.graduation_year = "2014"
u.save
```

The problem is, I can't figure out how to setup the controller and a form to do that. How can I do it? Please note the relationship between user and the student profile.

Comment: did you resolve this and do you mind posting back your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Watch this rails cast episode http://railscasts.com/episodes/210-customizing-devise

For the profile I think you just need to add the field at the new page form and in the user model make it accept nested attributes. To know what's the profile you could have a select box and a before filter to see what's the profile based on that value

Answer (score 0):

My best recommendation here is to override the Devise views and registrations controller and use form objects for signing up the user. Here's a great resource on form objects: http://blog.jasonharrelson.com/blog/2014/04/06/how-i-design-rails-applications-part-2-form-objects/

[ActiveModel::Model](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Model.html) is really useful for creating form objects, though there are some gems some people prefer to use, such as [reform](https://github.com/apotonick/reform).

I hope that helps!